# How to add the trailing slash in general for an Apache + CDN architecture (without using Apache mod_rewrite)?

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite, amazon-cloudfront, mod-alias

I would like to add the trailing slash in general when it is absent in the request URL:

> when user requests `https://example.com/blog`, it should be redirected to `https://example.com/blog/`
>
> when user requests `https://example.com/abc.jpg`, it should be served as it is

When the server is `Apache`, it seems it is usually done by `mod_rewrite`. Unfortunately, our system include a `CDN` (`AWS CloudFront`) which causes problem when use `mod_rewite`: the request will be redirected to the origin server, and the URL in the browser changes to origin server's URL.

I also tried `mod_alias`'s `RedirectMatch`. But it seems it is too difficult for regular expressions to accomplish complex match patterns (in fact, it needs regex not match pattern).

So how to add the trailing slash in general for an `Apache` + `CDN` architecture?

Edit:

Thanks to Michael, it turns out that whitelist the Host header in CloudFront solves my problem: the redirected URL remains the same as the old one (with slash).

Comment: There should be a simple way to configure mod_rewrite to do the right thing.  Failing that, in the CloudFront Cache Behavior settings, if you whitelist the `Host` header for forwarding to the origin, your Apache server will see that hostname instead of its own in the incoming request, causing the generated redirects to be correct. Try that?

Comment: How are requests being sent to the CDN? "the request will be redirected to the origin server" - that is perhaps indicative of an incorrectly (or incomplete) configured proxy? "it needs regex not match pattern" - "regex" and "pattern" are often used interchangeably in this context to mean the same thing (ie. a regex). mod_rewrite enables you to use _conditions_ as well - which _might_ be required in this instance (but not necessarily because of a regex-limitation).

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Whitelist Host header works! Thank you!

Comment: @shintaroid You should add that as an answer and accept it to remove it from the unanswered question queue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This answer does not solve the problem refer to the title. However, since the key problem is how to redirect to the right url, I accept the following answer. It is credited to Michael

The reason that it redirects to origin URL is due to CloudFront's header forwarding. If we whitelist the `Host` header, it will redirect to the same domain as user's request.